# PKIX certificate path error : ok with java, not with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, https, liferay, pkix

We use Java JDK 1.8.0_112, Tomcat 8.0.32 and Liferay framework 7.0-GA4.

We have to send a POST request to some HTTPS URL.

Using a simple Java class, with all the code in the main function, everything works fine.

Using Tomcat (with Liferay framework) it does not work and we get the following exception.

```
 PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException
```

Using SSL debug startup option (`-Djavax.net.debug=trustmanager,SSL`) we can see that the truststore which is used is indeed the same in both cases: `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_112/jre/lib/security/cacerts`.

The code requesting the URL in the Java console/main function app and the code run by Tomcat is strictly the same (using `java.net.HttpURLConnection`).

If I try to replace the URL I request by "https://google.com", it works both in main function and web app code.

I'm quite lost: If the certificate is indeed not valid why does it work using `java MyClass`? If the certificate is valid, why does it not work in the web app?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your tomcat app server, that is failing, is running with a different version of the JRE than the one used by your unit test that worked?

Maybe it is using a previous version that is not compatible with a strong cipher, that would fail even if we can make sure that we use the same keystore file.  In that case you should just make sure that the JRE versions are the same.

Have a look at https://www.java.com/en/jre-jdk-cryptoroadmap.html to see the detailed documentation and compatibility matrix between JRE versions and cipher algorithms.